# Constructing a noncommutative algebra from a commutative algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, operator-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, noncommutative-algebra

I was told at a conference that one way to construct a noncommutative algebra from a commutative one is to "replace the product of finite spaces (which on the level of continuous functions corresponds to a tensor product of finite-dimensional abelian C*-algebras) with the tensor product of finite-dimensional matrix algebras (i.e. a UHF algebra)."  I am a graduate student at the beginning of my thesis work and I have tried to find a reference about said method that I can study.  I would appreciate any suggestions for references or directions to consider.

Comment: I think you are looking for *Bratteli diagrams*. A nice textbook is Davidson's *C$^*$-algebras by example*.

Comment: This construction is a special case of the following. Take a finite product of matrix algebras over the ring (not necessarily of the same size), and then take a direct limit of these (possibly with the maps between them given by matrix algebra maps; in this case, it amounts to tensoring with an arbitrary AF algebra, but it is very interesting to consider other types of algebra homomorphisms connecting them).

Comment: Can you also please recommend a reference?  As I am a novice in the subject, I am trying to get a good foundation in things of this nature.  Thanks so much for posting a detailed comment!